# `Assembly.Load` in a separate folder

Tags: c#

As a continuation of my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30507492/deserialization-exception-in-appdomain).

I load DLL through this code.
Example 1:

```
var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile("C:\\Temp\\PROCESSOR\\SKM.dll");
```

And that's work fine.

But I use serialization that internally use this code, example 2:

```
var ass1 = Assembly.Load("SKM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");
```

And this code throws an exception: `System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Unable to find assembly "SKM, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null".` - that's because the DLL in a separate folder.

How to force CLR to see DLL in separate directory (not in subfolders of main application)?

I tried this:

1. `<codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="C:\\Temp\\PROCESSOR\\SKM.dll"/>` - do not work because it works only for subfolders.
2. `<probing privatePath="paths"/>` - do not work because it works only for subfolders.
3. First run first example, and then run second example. But even if the `SKM.dll` already loaded, CLR does not see my assembly.

Comment: Side note but you're getting the FullPath() of a full path.

Comment: Maybe catching AppDomain.AssemblyResolve and calling Assembly.LoadFrom with the fullPath from there is an option.

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net

Comment: The correct way to mark your question as "solved" is not to change the title, but to post the answer to your question (which you've done) and mark that answer as the accepted one (which you have not done).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found resolution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373100/how-to-add-folder-to-assembly-search-path-at-runtime-in-net).

Just adding an event to `AssemblyResolve`:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
{
    string fileName = new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";
    string assemblyPath = Path.Combine("C:\\Temp\\PROCESSOR", fileName);
    var assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
    return assembly;
};
```

And if DLL can not be found standard way, the event fired and load DLL from my folder.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you don't want to go with example 1 if you know where the DLL is?

If you really don't then one option would be to register the DLL in the GAC.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dkkx7f79%28v=vs.110%29.aspx